# Publish can't find gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, visual-studio-2017, publish

Visual Studio 2017 15.7.3, SDK Net Core 2.1, Windows 7 Ultimate

If I open a `Developer Command Prompt` and run gulp from the root of my project it works.

If I open a `Command Prompt` from Windows, navigate to the root of my project, and run gulp I get

`'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

If I search the system drive I cannot find a gulp.exe or gulp.com.
I also looked directly in the `C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Roaming\npm`and the `npm-cache` folders and could not find the `executable`.

In my `Project.csproj` file I have

```
<Target Name="MyPublishScripts" BeforeTargets="BeforePublish">
    <Exec Command="npm install" />
    <Exec Command="gulp" />
    <Exec Command="ng build" />
</Target>
```

When I Publish it crashes on the `gulp` command with `is not recognized ...`.

I've tried `"%APPDATA%\npm\gulp" and "%APPDATA%\npm-cache\gulp"` and `gulp is not recognized...`

In the `Output` window I can see that `%APPDATA%` is properly interpreted as `C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Roaming`.

`C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Roaming\npm` is in the path for both `command prompts`.

When `gulp` successfully runs from the `Developer Command Prompt` what path is being used?

My main question is what path would I use in the `.csproj` for `gulp`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install gulp-cli for this.
You can install gulp as a global npm module.

Try following on command-prompt.

```
npm install gulp-cli -g
npm install gulp -g
gulp --help
```

Let me know if you are still facing the same issue

Comment: npm install --global gulp-cli was sufficent.  install npm must have just installed it locally.